# Feature layer is in WGS 84 and Esri map is Web Mercator

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have published a shapefile on ArcGIS Server, now want to add it to map. I used feature layer to add it to map but it does not display. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer

  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [69.3451, 30.3753],
      zoom:6
    });

    /****************************************************************
     * Add feature layer - A FeatureLayer at minimum should point
     * to a URL to a feature service or point to a feature collection 
     * object.
     ***************************************************************/


    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("url");

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is my shapefile is in WGS 1984 and the Esri map projection is Web Mercator. Is this the problem? I have tried to display with dynamic layer but same result. My shapefile is not showing in any case.

Comment: Have you tried publishing the shapefile in the desired projection?  It's far less efficient, but not impossibly so.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple fix:
In my case I copied/pasted your code, set the URL to an internal service that I knew worked. Then I noticed you defined your URL as a string not a variable. So I commented it out and showed a working example.  Good Luck...

```
    var url = "http://gis02:81/arcgis/rest/services/CIDataTest/FeatureServer/0"

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(url);  //<<url is a variable
 //var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("url");  //<< url is a String
```

Comment: shouldnt they both work?

Comment: No the string is just the letters url, the variable has the url http://... as it's value, you want the variable so it knows were the service is..

Comment: Add this to your example and you will see it's not a projection issue as the Tree data is in PA state plane,   var url = "http://maps.allentownpa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ParksMemorialTrees/FeatureServer/0"

    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(url);
  //var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("url");

Comment: thanks yes i have solved the problem .i was giving string not a variable